# Disable buttons while data loading

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, mobile-application, loading

I have a view in my mobile app with two buttons, before allowing user to click on them I need to wait for some data to load, should I disable them while it happens ?

Should I show a loading indicator on them ? (seems weird to show loading indicator since user hasn't clicked on them yet)

What should I do to convey to the user that it will soon be allowed to click on those buttons

Comment: There's an answer to this question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067042/5765312)

Comment: @Danielillo where ?

Comment: Click the link on the previous comment

Comment: I just don't see which answer answers my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three options:

- On the button → **Busy Button**
- On the screen → **Busy Dialog**
- On the section → **Busy Indicator**

### Busy button

The message is on the button. The button itself shows what is happening while being indirectly disabled:

[image]

<sub>*More <kbd>Busy Button</kbd>  examples on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=UI%20busy%20button&tbm=isch&hl=en&tbs=rimg:CQWF13_1QUY6OYf0FyGd31zew8AEAsgIMCgIIABAAOgQIARAA&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&sa=X&ved=0CAIQrnZqFwoTCPjr8ZCItfkCFQAAAAAdAAAAABBB&biw=1506&bih=1207)*</sub>

### Busy Dialog

If the message must block the screen:

[image: busy alert]

<sub>*[Image source](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/busydialog/)*</sub>

### Busy Indicator

If the message is part of the interface while the user interacts on the page, on completion the indicator can be replaced by the button:

[image: Busy Indicator]

<sub>*[More about Busy Indicators](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/busy-indicator/)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rest of the activity/page you are creating. Is the rest of the page useless until the button has been loaded? Then you should just create a progress page in front of it.

Are there many other things the user might do? Then you'll want a placeholder component. You've seen this certainly on other webpages or apps. They display a slowly pulsing "faceless" component before displaying the actual active component.

Comment: the user can't do anything on this page until button is loaded but he can still read some already loaded pieces of information while the rest loads - so I thought not to put a loader on the all view